# Creating a Facebook share button with customized url, title and image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share-button

Facebook used to allow custom parameters in the Facebook share button, but it is not working now. What I need is to create a Facebook share button which will have a custom title, url, image, description, etc. It cannot be done using meta tags because there are multiple share buttons on a single page. Each should have a different title, urls, images etc. I heard it can be done using the Facebook app - using app id or something.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
<a title="send to Facebook" 
  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT"
  target="_blank">
```

Comment: <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $pageUrl; ?>" title="Facebook share" ><img style="margin-right: 10px;" src="_images/facebook_share.png" alt="facebook share button"/></a>

Comment: _“It cannot be done using meta tags, because there are a number of share buttons in a single page”_ – so all of them are sharing the _same_ URL? One URL == one Open Graph object. If you want to use different Open Graph objects, use different URLs. If this is not an option (although sharing the same object with multiple images/descriptions does not make much sense – when those posts are _re-shared_ on FB directly, FB will pull the info from the URL anyways), the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) still allows you to set those parameters at runtime.

Comment: urls are different. Or is it possible in PHP to goto another page if the visitor is from facebook @CBroe

Comment: So if the URLs are different, then why can’t you just provide the individual meta data under each of them? / Facebook appends a certain amount of tracking parameters to links from their news feed, so you could look for these and then redirect if necessary.

Comment: ooops sorry the urls are the same. I mean the title, description and image will be different. @CBroe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that we can't post shares for individual topics or articles within a page. It appears Facebook just wants us to share entire pages (based on url only).

There's also their new [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), but even though they claim it can do all of what the old sharer.php could do, that doesn't appear to be true.

And here's [Facebooks 'best practices'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/) for sharing.

Comment: dead link: http://www.phpscholar.com/tutorials/custom-thumbnail-title-and-description-for-facebook-share-using-open-graph

Answer (score 5):

This is the code as 2017:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'facebook-share-dialog','width=626,height=436');return false;">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Facebook now takes all data from OG metatags.

NOTE: This code assumes you have OG metatags on in site's code.

[Source](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-share-webpages-with-facebook)

Answer (score 5):

**Use facebook feed dialog instead of share dialog.**

Example:

[https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1389892087910588
&redirect_uri=https://scotch.io
&link=https://scotch.io
&picture=http://placekitten.com/500/500
&caption=This%20is%20the%20caption
&description=This%20is%20the%20description](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1389892087910588%20&redirect_uri=https://scotch.io%20&link=https://scotch.io%20&picture=http://placekitten.com/500/500%20&caption=This%20is%20the%20caption%20&description=This%20is%20the%20description)

Comment: @GijoVarghese Remove spaces in the url. Happened to me

Comment: @GijoVarghese Also check app id and app domain in facebook developer console

Comment: This has been deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Crude, but it works on our system:

```
<div class="block-share spread-share p-t-md">
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.voteleavetakecontrol.org/our_affiliates&title=Farmers+for+Britain+have+made+the+sensible+decision+to+Vote+Leave.+Be+part+of+a+better+future+for+us+all.+Please+share!" 
     target="_blank">
    <button class="btn btn-social btn-facebook">
      <span class="icon icon-facebook">
      </span> 
      Share on Facebook
    </button>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FarmersForBritain" target="_blank">
    <button class="btn btn-social btn-facebook">
      <span class="icon icon-facebook">
      </span>
      Like  on Facebook
    </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: will there be any error if i use this method in 2018?