# Facebook share button using custom URL, title, description from surrounding content

Tags: facebook

I have a webpage that features many sections/articles. Each section has a fb share icon but, does not have a unique URL. When a user shares a specific section, I would like to use the title, description and image from the specific section vs og tags at the page level. I see this related question but, hoping it is outdated [Creating a Facebook share button with customized url, title and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877149/creating-a-facebook-share-button-with-customized-url-title-and-image). Any suggestions is appreciated, even workarounds.

Comment: You're hoping wrong. Facebook has restricted this even more recently. Go create unique URLs, that is the only proper solution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, much appreciated.